# Form alter on dynamic forms

Tags: forms

Say one needs to alter a form with a dynamic id, for example `nodequeue_arrange_subqueue_form_12`, where 12 is the dynamic element of the $form_id, is there a way to target this type of form_id? Some sort of wildcard?

I have resolved to using the following:

```
if (strpos($form_id, 'nodequeue_arrange_subqueue_form') !== false) {
  $form['add']['nid']['#size'] = 90; 
}
```

Seems there must be a cleaner more "drupalish" way of doing this.

Is there a way to use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` form of form_alter?

**UPDATE:**

Nevermind, `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` works fine even without the dynamic placeholder.
Left the post in case anyone stumbles here with the same question.

Comment: It's hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter that you are using now.

Comment: @AyeshK Yeah, just add that with a link to the docs as the answer so it can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @AyeshK - Thanks bro, updated the answer. If you want easy karma just slap up the answer and I shall accept it.